# refrescar tabla desde una api Angular 6

Tags: angular6

Hola no se en q estoy fallando estoy llenando una tabla desde un servicio (API) y no se por que no se actualiza bien si responde al segundo producto que agrego pero no al primero y una vez q comenzó a agregar después continua perfectamente lo mismo al eliminar (la api es php ).-

> en el componente

```
agregarTablaEdit(dib: any)
{
this.dibServ.altaDib(this.dib).subscribe();
this.ngOnInit();
this.RefrezcarDatos();
this.router.navigate(['/dibEditClean'])
}
```

> Miren que puevo con tres métodos con "ngOnInit" una "funcion refrezcar datos " y "enviando a otro componente y regresando" este ultimo me funciona pero me reinicia las variables cada vez inicia

```
 RefrezCardatos(){
this.dibServ.obtenerDib().subscribe(
result => this.DIBcompu = result);
this.dibServ.obtenerDibFecha().subscribe(
result => this.DIBFEC = result);}
```

> en html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of DIBcompu">
    <td>{{item.caravana}}</td>
    <td>{{item.raza}}</td>
    <td>{{item.peso1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.peso2}}</td>
    <td>{{item.adpv1| number:'.3-3'}}</td>
    <td>{{item.peso3}}</td>
    <td>{{item.adpv2 |number:'.3-3'}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ciclicidad}}</td>
    <td>{{item.numero}}</td>
    <td>{{item.utero}}</td>
    <td>{{item.gdr}}</td>
    <td>{{item.servicio}}</td>
    <td>{{item.peso4}}</td>
    <td>  
      <button class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditarAnimal"(click)="EditDIB(item,divFecha)" ><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning " (click)="bajaDibTemp(item.id)"   ><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
    </td>
```

Comment: UTILIZAS un ORM? talves cuando levantas tu backend la bd este totalmente limpia

Comment: discúlpame con limpia te refieres a vacía ?